# Can rabbits be tamed and bred?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing a custom map and I wanted to tame and breed a few rabbits in the custom map pet store. But then I realized I wasn't able to tame or breed rabbits. I'm not sure whether I really can tame and breed rabbits but I'm not doing it right, or if I was just being dumb and not realizing taming and breeding rabbits is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can breed rabbits. For this, you can use [carrots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Carrot), [golden carrots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Golden_Carrot), or dandelions.

It was by the way possible to tame them prior to [14w34a patch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/14w34a), but now it's impossible.

Source : [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit#Breeding)